# Image classification, narrow domain with custom labels

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, deep-learning

Let's suppose I would like to **classify motorbikes by model**.

- there are **couple of hundreds models of motorbikes** I'm interested in.
- I do have **tens, sometimes hundreds** of pictures of each motorbike model.

Can you please point me to the **practical example** that demonstrates how to **train model on your data** and then use it to classify images? It needs to be a **deep learning** model, not simple logistic regression.

I'm not sure about it, but it seems like I can't use pre-trained neural net because it has been trained on wide range of objects like cat, human, cars etc. They may be not too good at distinguishing the motorbike nuances I'm interested in.

I found couple of such examples (tensorflow has one), but sadly, all of them were using pre-trained model. None of it had example how to train it on your own dataset.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on SO and since this question is not about a specific programming problem per se, I recommend you ask this at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

In cases like yours you either use transfer learning or fine tuning. If you have more then thousand images of motorbikes I would use fine tuning and if you have less transfer learning.

Fine tuning is using a pre trained model and using a different classifier part. Then the new classifier part maybe the last 1-2 layers of the trained model are trained to your dataset.

Transfer learning means using a pre trained model and letting it output features for an input image. Now you use a new classifier based on those features. Maybe a SVM or a logistic regression.

An example for this can be seen here: https://github.com/cpra/dlvc2016/blob/master/lectures/lecture10.pdf. slide 33.

Answer (score 1):

This paper [Quick, Draw! Doodle Recognition](http://Quick,%20Draw!%20Doodle%20Recognition) from a [kaggle challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/quickdraw-doodle-recognition) may be similar enough to what you are doing. The code is on [github](https://github.com/kristineguo/quickdraw). You may need some [data augmentation](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/data-augmentation-techniques-in-cnn-using-tensorflow-371ae43d5be9) if you only have a few hundred images for each category.

Comment: this was from: kaggle.com/c/quickdraw-doodle-recognition. the stanford paper is here: cs229.stanford.edu/proj2018/report/98.pdf – Ray Tayek 1 min ago. can't seem to edit the post. my nephew wrote a paper about the stanford paper. it is here: https://github.com/ChandlerTayek/CS_674_Project

Comment: also, you might consider https://machinelearningmastery.com/transfer-learning-for-deep-learning/

Answer (score 0):

What you want is pretty EZ. Follow the darknet YOLO implementation

Instruction: `https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/`

Code `https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet`

Training YOLO on COCO
You can train YOLO from scratch if you want to play with different training regimes, hyper-parameters, or datasets. Here's how to get it working on the COCO dataset.

Get The COCO Data
To train YOLO you will need all of the COCO data and labels. The script scripts/get_coco_dataset.sh will do this for you. Figure out where you want to put the COCO data and download it, for example:

```
cp scripts/get_coco_dataset.sh data
cd data
bash get_coco_dataset.sh
```

Add your data inside and make sure it is same as testing samples. 
Now you should have all the data and the labels generated for Darknet.

Then call training script with the pre-trained weight.

Keep in mind that only training on your motorcycle may not result in good estimation. There would be biased result coming out, I red it somewhere b4.

The rest is all inside the link. Good luck